# onNewIntent() lifecycle and registered listeners

Tags: android, android-intent, lifecycle

I'm using a singleTop Activity to receive intents from a search-dialog via [`onNewIntent()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent%28android.content.Intent%29).

What I noticed is that `onPause()` is called before `onNewIntent()`, and then afterwards it calls `onResume()`.  Visually:

- search dialog initiated
- search intent fired to activity
- `onPause()`
- `onNewIntent()`
- `onResume()`

The problem is that I have listeners registered in `onResume()` that get removed in `onPause()`, but they are needed inside of the `onNewIntent()` call. Is there a standard way to make those listeners available?

Answer (score 325, accepted):

`onNewIntent()` is meant as entry point for singleTop activities which already run somewhere else in the stack and therefore can't call `onCreate()`. From activities lifecycle point of view it's therefore needed to call `onPause()` before `onNewIntent()`. I suggest you to rewrite your activity to not use these listeners inside of `onNewIntent()`. For example most of the time my `onNewIntent()` methods simply looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    // getIntent() should always return the most recent
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

With all setup logic happening in `onResume()` by utilizing `getIntent()`.

Comment: @Rodja will you please comment on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19092631/logout-from-the-application-android/19092683?noredirect=1#19092683 also

Comment: Related to original question: keep in mind if you move the code to handle the search `Intent` into `onResume()`, your Activity will probably try to execute a search every time it resumes, probably not the behavior you want.

Comment: Rodja says: From activities lifecycle point of view it's therefore needed to call onPause() before onNewIntent()

Android did not NEED to design it this way. Your activity has already gone through its lifecycle through to resume(). No NEED for android to call onPause() then call onResume() again. If the app is resumed the os could simply call onNewIntent() and stay in the resumed state.

Comment: Rodja says: From activities lifecycle point of view it's therefore needed to call onPause() before onNewIntent()

Android didn't NEED to design it so. Your activity has already gone through its lifecycle to resume. If the act is resumed they could simply call onNewIntent() and stay in the resumed.
 
The problem with Android's sequence is that it makes it impossible to distinguish between onPause due to user action vs onPause due to a background intent. If you want to act onPause only in the case of user action you are screwed because you wont know till the future why you go the onPause().

Comment: Important point to note is that getIntent() still returns the original Intent. You can use setIntent(Intent) to update to the new Intent.

Comment: You said, "singleTop activities which already run somewhere else in the stack" but according to the documentation the the singleTop activity will always be present at the top of the history stack. Here is the link   [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP]

Comment: @TheHunter: That is not true. If these Activities would always be at the top of the history stack you would not be able to start new Activities in this task. According to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP "the activity will not be launched **IF** it is already running at the top of the history stack", implying that it also can be not at the top. So it's already been created and running, hence the lifecycle will just call "onNewIntent".

Comment: @Rodja: The statement "the activity will not be launched if it is already running at the top of the history stack" means that if the activity is present on top of the stack then the activity will not be launched. I do not understand why you are looking at the word **IF** is such a different manner.

Comment: I have a singleTop activity called from an alarm. About onNewIntent() the docs say "An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so you can count on onResume() being called after this method." But setting breakpoints I see onNewIntent() being called after onResume(). onResume() is **not** called after my onNewIntent().

Comment: After wasting so much time trying to figure out whether the intent in new or existing on onResume(), I wish I knew about this function earlier. Thanks

Comment: is it okay to set intent to null after using the intent in onresume()?

Answer (score 17):

Note: Calling a lifecycle method from another one is not a good practice. In below example I tried to achieve that your onNewIntent will be always called irrespective of your Activity type.

OnNewIntent() always get called for singleTop/Task activities except for the first time when activity is created. At that time onCreate is called providing to solution for few queries asked on this thread.

You could invoke your Intent handler by putting it into onCreate method like

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedState){
    super.onCreate(savedState);
    handleIntent(getIntent());
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
  super.onNewIntent(intent);
  handleIntent(intent);
}

protected void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
  //code
}
```

Comment: Generally not a good idea to be calling lifecycle methods directly, no? Maybe harmless, or maybe some base implementation of onNewIntent() assumes that onPause() has already been called? Presumably safer to encapsulate the app code in a method callable from both places.

Comment: Agreed. We ran into a few edge cases using this approach. Best avoided.

Comment: Yeah .. me too agree on avoiding this ... this was for those who want to invoke onNewIntent from onCreate as well.