# Is there a way to grab an NFC tag without having onPause/onResume fire?

Tags: android, nfc, onnewintent

looking at this question:
[onNewIntent() lifecycle and registered listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619883/onnewintent-lifecycle-and-registered-listeners)

I see that the OP is experiencing the same problem I am, but I'm not clear on why the solution provided serves his purposes.

When a user taps their NFC to the device, I am collecting the info from the incoming Intent, however, I don't want either onPause or onResume to fire as I gather this data.  If there is no way to prevent that from happening, is there another way for me to gather the incoming NFC info other than by listening for onNewIntent?  I have a bunch of logic in onResume that is entirely unprepared to suddenly deal with being called out of the blue when the user hasn't left the app... I'm hoping to avoid having to refactor my code to deal with this unexpected contingency.  Thanks in advance.