# Same activity not opened when I reenter the app

Tags: android

In my application I have several activities. One of them being the `MainActivity`. The thing is ,whenever I am inside another activity `SecondActivity` and press the home button (middle button on android devices) and I go to the home screen, then reenter the app from the application list, I am being directed to the `MainActivity` of the app and not the `SecondActivity`.

I placed some logs inside the both activities and whenever I press the home button from `SecondActivity`, the `onPause` of `SecondActivity` is being called. And when I get back to the app, the `MainActivity` comes up and consequently the `onStop` and `onDestroy` of `SecondActivity` is being called (which is the normal and expected behavior I assume).

My question is, how to make the app enter the `SecondActivity` (or any other activity that I left from, given of course the android system does not call `onDestroy` and kill the activity to get some memory.

I have the below in my code, unsure if it causes issues.

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be occurring. Unless the app has been destroyed it will start on the activity you left off on, starting at onResume() in the life cycle. Something you are doing is altering the native Android functionality. From what you are saying it would either be something in the Manifest or in your SecondActivity code.

Comment: Complimenting zgc7009 that should be the case and you are most likely setting the `noHistory` to true on SecondActivity or you are setting `launchMode` parameter that does not keep the state of the activity.

Comment: I have never personally used onNewIntent so I am not sure if it is possible if it is causing the issue. Are you using it for something specific?

Comment: yes i do use it for a purpose when i come back to the app using an intent... here is a good explanation... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619883/onnewintent-lifecycle-and-registered-listeners

Comment: @tony9099 I wouldn't think that `onNewIntent` would cause an issue with what you are seeing, but I don't know it well enough. Unless the intent is not in a good state when it comes back and then system decides to close and finish SecondActivity at that point.  Thereby bringing you back to the next one on the stack which is MainActivity.

Comment: I think the answer is because I am sending with the intent that will open the SecondActivity, the i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); which doesnt store the activity being opened in the stack

Comment: @tony9099 Yeah, the noHistory flag means that when you leave it will not remember it on the stack anymore.  That sounds right.