# Listen to Intent changes

Tags: android, android-intent, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I´m currently launching an Amazon FireTV app via the dial protocol with a parameter. This parameter can be accessed in the `onCreate()` by an intent like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
paramter = intent.getStringExtra("com.amazon.extra.DIAL_PARAM");
```

Is there some way to know, if this intent changes while the FireTV app is running, like a listener? I know, this could be done with a `while` loop constantly checking if the parameter changed, but this seems not to be a good solution. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [onNewIntent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent)) of Activity, that will trigger each time the Activity receives a new Intent.

This works exactly the same as for standard Android.

Comment: thanks a lot, with your help i found this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619883/onnewintent-lifecycle-and-registered-listeners), which resolved the problem perfectly