# How to count saved data from SMS and show that number in Textview

Tags: java, android

The Android app that I am going to build is SMS Vote app.
To explain my project,

My MainActivity supposed to be receive the SMS data from the RedirectActivity and recognize whether it is 1 or 2 and then increment the variable `numOf1` or `numOf2` as well as `total`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int numOf1 = 0;
    private int numOf2 = 0;
    private int sum = 0;
    private TextView number1 ;
    private TextView number2 ;
    private TextView total;
    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("text");
        if(data.equals("1")){
            numOf1++;
            number1.setText(Integer.toString(numOf1));
        }
        else if(data.equals("2")){
            numOf2++;
            number2.setText(Integer.toString(numOf2));
        }
        sum = numOf1 + numOf2;
        total.setText(Integer.toString(sum));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        number1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number1);
        number2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number2);
        total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);
    }

    @Override

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }


    public boolean onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.set:
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, setting.class));
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The RedirectActivity will receive the SMS data via Intent from SMSReceiver class.

```
public class RedirectActivity extends Activity {
    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String text = intent.getStringExtra("text");


        Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("text", text);
        startActivity(i);

    }

}
```

SMSReceiver class

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    static final String logTag = "SmsReceiver";
    static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";

    @Override

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] msgs = null;
        String str = "";
        if (bundle != null)
        {
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i=0; i<msgs.length; i++){
                msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])pdus[i]);
                str += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            }

            Intent i=new Intent(context,RedirectActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("text", str);
            context.startActivity(i);

        }

    }
}
```

The problem that I am being encountered is somehow whenever I send the message with 1 or 2 via localhost 5554 and receive it, my app doesn't count at all.

How can I solve it? :D

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to move the code inside `onNewIntent()` in `MainActivity` to `onCreate`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    number1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number1);
    number2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.number2);
    total = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.total);

    String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("text");
    if(data.equals("1")){
        numOf1++;
        number1.setText(Integer.toString(numOf1));
    }
    else if(data.equals("2")){
        numOf2++;
        number2.setText(Integer.toString(numOf2));
    }
    sum = numOf1 + numOf2;
    total.setText(Integer.toString(sum));

}
```

But the reason that your code inside `onNewIntent` is not work, because you haven't call `setIntent(intent)`. You should call `setIntent(intent)` before you call `getInent()`.

```
 @Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
    ...

}
```

See this for more detail of `onNewIntent()` [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619883/onnewintent-lifecycle-and-registered-listeners)

I hope this will help.

Comment: Have you check that your SMSReceiver  is configure property?
I afraid that your SMSReceiver does not receive when there's new coming SMS.