# MainAcitivity Does not enter onNewIntent Method and call onCreate Again even it's SingleTask

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, deep-linking

to prevent the app from reload after clicking on deeplink. I have made the lunch mode for the splash activity singleTask and handled any new intent in onnewintent method

```
   <activity
        android:name=".activities.SplashActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Splash">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
       >
    </activity>
```

also i made the maniActivity to be signleTask to prevent reload every time user open deeplink. the splash call onNewIntent smoothly but the mainactivity recreated every time how to make the MainActivity  call onNewIntent instead of calling onCreate I have tried to add flags  `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` to MainActivity intent but it's not working

```
//splashActivty
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setIntent` and then continue execution in `onResume`.

Looking at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619883/onnewintent-lifecycle-and-registered-listeners) I would say the startActivity might be a problem.